# Combine two images in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation

I want to create an image by combining two images so that first image is set as border of second image using c# code.

Comment: You really need to add more detail to this question to demonstrate what you understand how to do, where you need help, what you've already tried. You see I've removed the superfluous information from your question.

Comment: I have two images like.. img1.jpg and img2.gif. So i want to set img2.gif as border of img1.jpg. The inner part of img1.gif is transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this articles on [combining images in C#](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/combining-images-with-csharp)

Just change it to work with two images, and manipulate the offset so one borders the other.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft

Our [DotImage Photo SDK](http://atalasoft.com/photofree) (which is free) can do this.

Load an image

```
AtalaImage img = new AtalaImage("file.jpg");
```

Load the border (assumes that it has tranparent in the middle, and is the same size)

```
OverlayCommand cmd = new OverlayCommand("border.png", new Point(0,0));
AtalaImage borderedImg = cmd.Apply(img).Image;
```

Save the final image

```
borderedImg.Save("final.jpg", new JpegEncoder(), null);
```